# MSSQL: Query to replace apostrophes with HTML ASCII code &#39;

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, ascii

I am working with an MSSQL 2008 database for which I have a simple update statement to commit data from a form to the database:

```
    UPDATE Product
    SET ProductDescription = @ProductDescription 
    WHERE ProductID = @ProductID
```

However many of the product descriptions that will be updated in the db have one or more single apostrophes `'` in their text. I need the `SQL UPDATE` statement to also convert those single apostrophes to the HTML ASCII code for single apostrophes `&#39;` before they are committed to the database.

One thing to note is that the column into the Product Description text will be updated is an `NTEXT` column.

How can this be done? Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Do you use any high-level language to run that Update statement? If so, such a high-level language provides escaping mechanisms. E.g. Java provides prepared statements for the same reason.

Comment: Why not store the plain, unaltered text in the database? Who says the product descriptions will always be output into HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE Product
    SET ProductDescription = REPLACE( @ProductDescription,'&#39;','''' )
    WHERE ProductID = @ProductID
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `REPLACE( @ProductDescription,''','&#39 ;' )`